# Parse different JSON responses without using POJO classes in Java

Tags: javascript, java, json

I am parsing JSON responses from REST API in Java, but I don't want to create a Java class (POJO) for each response (responses have different data structures and fields). Is there a more generic JSON parser in Java that is similar to the straightforward syntax of JavaScript?

The JSON below is the result of just one of the many REST endpoints

```json
{
    "f1" : "volume",
    "f2" : "gender",
    "f3" : "days",
    "f4" : [{
            "id" : "F",
            "name" : "female",
            "values" : [{
                    "name" : "September",
                    "value" : 12
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "id" : "M",
            "name" : "male",
            "values" : [{
                    "name" : "September",
                    "value" : 11
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In JavaScript, to access the value for female:

```js
jsonRoot.f4[0].values[0].value
```

which is neater than to have to create numerous Java classes. Can you suggest something similar or a way to avoid creating many POJOs?

Comment: Yes, use a library like Jackson.

Comment: @duffymo Can you give an example of how to do that in Jackson, based on the example above? The examples I've seen online still uses Java classes.

Comment: If you use a ScriptEngine then you can use JavaScript in Java (if you want).

Comment: Sure, parse it to a JSONObject.  Or try Nashorn JavaScript engine that's built into JDK8 itself.  Some effort on your part would be noteworthy.

Comment: @duffymo Can't use JDK8, our environment is restricted to 7 for the time being. Will look into Nashorn though, if it can be plugged in to 7.

Comment: What do you mean by "without using Java classes?" That and primitives are all there are in Java, and none of the primitives can handle arrays and objects from JSON. Even string values require instances of the `String` class. Your JavaScript example is using JavaScript objects, just the syntax is cleaner.

Comment: @blm I mean using Java POJO classes for each kind of JSON response I am getting. Most examples online of JSON processing in Java always involves POJO. I've edited my question.

Comment: Again, that (and primitives) is all there is in Java. This can't be done without creating instances of Java classes, like `Map`s and arrays and `String`s and various subclasses of `Number`. Your JavaScript is using POJOs (Plain Old JavaScript Objects :-) ) as well. `jsonRoot` is a JavaScript Object with an `f4` property which is an array (a type of JavaScript Object), the first element of which is another Object having a `values` property, etc.

Comment: JDK7 has Rhino; you can easily use it.

Comment: You've had the power to parse JSON all along without an additional dependency; you didn't know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you imported the jar of **com.google.gson**.You can get the value like this:

```
     String str="{" +
            "    \"f1\" : \"volume\"," +
            "    \"f2\" : \"gender\"," +
            "    \"f3\" : \"days\"," +
            "    \"f4\" : [{" +
            "            \"id\" : \"F\"," +
            "            \"name\" : \"female\"," +
            "            \"values\" : [{" +
            "                    \"name\" : \"September\"," +
            "                    \"value\" : 12" +
            "                }" +
            "            ]" +
            "        }, {" +
            "            \"id\" : \"M\"," +
            "            \"name\" : \"male\"," +
            "            \"values\" : [{" +
            "                    \"name\" : \"September\"," +
            "                    \"value\" : 11" +
            "                }" +
            "            ]" +
            "        }" +
            "    ]" +
            "}";
    JsonParser parser=new JsonParser();
    JsonObject object=(JsonObject)parser.parse(str);
    String value=object.get("f4").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject()
            .get("values").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject()
            .get("value").getAsString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Jackson Mapping to `Map<String, Object>` is also ok:

```
    String data = "{\"f4\":[1, 2]}"

    try {
        Map<String, Object> value = mapper.readValue(data, Map.class);
        System.out.println(value.get("f4"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The value of defining POJO object for this is static type checking, and I still recommend doing so.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s="[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
    Object obj=JSONValue.parse(s);
    JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
    System.out.println(array.get(1));       
    System.out.println(((JSONObject)array.get(1)).get("1"));
```

[more example](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/tree/master/src/test/java/org/json/simple)

[json-simple.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `org.json` library.

If you use maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20150729</version>
    </dependency>
```

Or download the jar: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Java example:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{'f1' : 'volume', 'f2' : 'gender', 'f3' : 'days'}"); // Truncated for example purpose

        String f1 = jsonObject.getString("f1");
        System.out.println(f1);
    }
}
```

Also you can access to arrays

```
JSONArray f4Array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("f4");
```

And then iterate over it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < f4Array.length(); i++){
        String id = f4Array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        String name = f4Array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(id);
        JSONArray values = f4Array.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("values");
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length(); j++){
            String dName = values.getJSONObject(j).getString("name");
            int dValue = values.getJSONObject(j).getInt("value");
            System.out.println(dName);
            System.out.println(dValue);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -3):

there's a parseJson() function in Jquery if you're using jQuery.

Comment: I'm using Java, not JavaScript

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  I've been using javascript and forgot that there's a java too.